# Bootbox + jQuery DataTables. Bootbox run function after pop-up

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, bootbox

I'm using Bootbox to display a pop-up that contains a table, this part works great.

But now I want to use the jQuery DataTables plugin on the just created table for sorting.
This requires me to call the DataTables plugin on the table I just created witthin the bootbox.

But I can't find any way to call a javascript/jQuery function after the bootbox pop-up has being created, if you write code inside the bootbox function it'll only happen when the bootbox pop up is closed.

How do I run a function after the bootbox pop-up has popped up and while it still is up?

```
$(document).on('click', ".myButton", function () {
        var userName = "<h2>"+ ($(this).data("username")) +"</h2>";
        var tableHeader = "<thead><tr>" +
                          "<th>Header 1</th>" +
                          "<th>Header 2</th>" +
                          "<th>Header 3</th>" +
                          "</tr></thead>";
        var tableData = $(this).data("value");

        var table = "<table id='myTable' class='table'>" + tableHeader + "<tbody>" + tableData + "</tbody>" + "</table>";
        bootbox.alert(userName + table, function (result) {
        });
    });
```

What I need to place within this code is basically this

```
var oTable = $('#myTable').dataTable({
          null, null, null
        ]
    });
```

It is possible that I need to destroy and recreate the datatables between the pop-ups but that isn't the issue right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually worked to just place it after the bootbox call. 
But can't this lead to desync issues? i.e if the user is on a slow computer or the table/bootbox is heavy then it'll try to call the dataTables plugin before the bootbox is actually finished

```
$(document).on('click', ".myButton", function () {
            var userName = "<h2>"+ ($(this).data("username")) +"</h2>";
            var tableHeader = "<thead><tr>" +
                              "<th>Header 1</th>" +
                              "<th>Header 2</th>" +
                              "<th>Header 3</th>" +
                              "</tr></thead>";
            var tableData = $(this).data("value");

            var table = "<table id='myTable' class='table'>" + tableHeader + "<tbody>" + tableData + "</tbody>" + "</table>";
            bootbox.alert(userName + table, function (result) {
            });

            var oTable = $('#myTable').dataTable({
                null, null, null
            ]
            });
});
```